# Does the notion of the earth as a planet within the Solar System exist in scripture?

Tags: surya, earth, astronomy

In other words, as an approximate sphere going round the Sun with other planets some closer to the Sun and some further away?

Whether this modern view of the Solar System exists in scripture has not been asked before.

Comment: I found in most probably in Swami Nigamananda's book: chalaa prithvi sthiraa bhaati.

Comment: its there in Navagraha worship in southindian temple where sun is at the center, it was belief held back from even Ramas period, standing proof is sethu samudhram navagriha with sun at the center

Answer (score 1):

As per Rigved - 1.35.6 (or 1.416),

[image: Rigved-1.35.6]

This verse is saying that Earth and some other mystical worlds(Not sure about their modern representations) are lightened up by Sun and in the second line of verse, it is explaining about Gravitational dependancies of planets on Sun, by giving analogy of Wheel of chariot, i.e., on the scopes of wheel, planets are situated and Sun is situated at axis of wheel, and this seems a perfect analogy of Solar system.